# How to set VirtualBox's machine-folder relative to current Vagrant Project?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

This is a follow-up question to
[How can I change where Vagrant looks for its virtual hard drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687648/how-can-i-change-where-vagrant-looks-for-its-virtual-hard-drive)

Is it possible to set the machine-folder relative/inside the current Vagrant project (maybe is there a provider-option for that) ?

Scenario: Vagrant project is stored on an external drive. The created machine files (vbox & vmdk) should also be stored on the external drive (whose mount point / drive letter differs from host to host and might change on the host itself) inside the same project folder. Therefore the general Virtualbox setting is not an option.
With that setting I should be able to have instantly the same state of my virtual machine on any host system.

(this is my first question here - please excuse any unintended noobness :) )

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.