# can vagrant machine folder be inside working directory

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Can vagrant create new machines inside working directory, not in VirtualBox default machine folder?
It would be nice if I could have everything related to the "project" under one directory.

Comment: Sure, why should it not be possible !? Check the settings.

Comment: I can't find any relevant setting in vagrantfile to set that.

Comment: 1. Check VirtualBox settings, set it there or 2. check Vagrant documentation.