# Problems moving vagrant.d outside of the home folder on OS X Mavericks (Vagrant 1.6.5)

Tags: vagrant, osx-mavericks

I want to move Vagrant off my machine to an external hard drive.

Following these articles:

[vagrant.d outside of the home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733681/vagrant-d-outside-of-the-home-folder)

http://emptysqua.re/blog/moving-virtualbox-and-vagrant-to-an-external-drive/

which is pretty straightforward, I assumed that all subsequent vagrant boxes would look to my new path `/Volumes/Vagrant/vagrant_home` but this isn't the case.

Exporting `VAGRANT_HOME` seems to not work as per the guide; it seems in my case the environmental variable is ignored. According to `shared_helpers.rb` if `VAGRANT_HOME` is not found it will default to `~/.vagrant.d` which in my case is what is happening. It's actually recreating `/Users/jeitnier/.vagrant.d`. Any new boxes are being created there instead of my `VAGRANT_HOME` path. It is defined in my `.bash_profile` and I also did the export from the command-line, again as the docs demonstrate.

`echo $VAGRANT_HOME` also shows the correct path of `/Volumes/Vagrant/vagrant_home` which is why I'm really stumped.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Jared, could you clarify what is the problem you are seeing? (And perhaps edit the question to reflect it.)

Comment: I confirm the same problem on Ubuntu:

`$ echo $VAGRANT_HOME
/hdd/.vagrant.d` `$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.6.5` `$ lsb_release -c 
Codename: trusty`

still creates `~/.vagrant.d`

Comment: @AlexBlex I was able to manually edit `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb` and set the path I wanted but I still ran into issues with the boxes stating they were created and running but nowhere to be found.

Comment: @JaredEitnier: Thanks. After re-login all works. Most likely I forgot to `source` the profile or something like that.

Comment: So you've got it creating new boxes where they ought to be & they show in the VirtualBox window? And it's not re-creating and reading from `.vagrant.d`?