# Download vagrant box to different drive

Tags: vagrant

I chose the D:\ drive during installation but when I download a vagrant box it downloads to my user directory on C:\ drive. I am using a SSD with hardly any available space. How do I make it download boxes to another drive?

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No, vagrant is a software used to configure development environment for programming. It is within the scope defined by SO. Search vagrant tag if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [VAGRANT_HOME environment variable](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html) to change the vagrant config / box download directory.

On Windows you should be able to use the `setx` command to change it, for example:

`setx VAGRANT_HOME "D:/vagrant"`

However, I found a similar [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733681/vagrant-d-outside-of-the-home-folder) where users are suggesting that the environment variable doesn't always work and that [changing the `@home_path` found in `vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.x.x.dev\lib\vagrant\environment.rb` worked for them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399795/3820845)

Comment: That has worked, files are going to D:\ drive now but I am still losing space from C: on first `vagrant up` (about 1gb I think roughly, could be a bit less).  Is it using this space to run image do you think?  The actual box downloaded to D: is only 300mb.

Comment: I suspect you are right. What are you using for your hypervisor? If you are using VirtualBox you can change the setting `Default Machine Folder` to change the location where the virtual hard drive's etc are stored.

Comment: So did you also set the VirtualBox Default Machine Folder to the D:/vagrant path?

Comment: I did this with a symlink via cmd and used `mklink /J e:\VagrantBoxes\boxes boxes`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller That’s an [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point), which is different from [NTFS symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) created with `/D` switch instead of `/J`. Both works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a link in `%UserProfile%\.vagrant.d\` pointing to a folder in your D drive. For Windows NTFS file system, both [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and [junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) works. To create a symbolic link, run following command in CMD (it doesn’t work in PowerShell):

```
mklink /d %UserProfile%\.vagrant.d\boxes D:\my-boxes-folder
```

Note that switch is case-insensitive, so `/d` is same as `/D`. To create a junction point, replace the `/d` with `/j`. For Unix-like system such as macOS or Linux, [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) should work.