# Vagrant changing files from c drive

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Laravel: 5.6 Vagrant: 2.1.1
When I installed the Vagrant, I noticed that all the files are in C drive (My C drive is SSD and I didn't want to do this). I followed [this process](https://harvsworld.com/2014/change-vagrant_home-directory-windows/) and moved both **.vagrant.d** and **.ssh** files to **E** drive. But I have two problems:

Firstly, for running each Vagrant command I need to provide the ID of my box. Otherwise, I get this error:

> Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
>   command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
>   get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
>   this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
>   Vagrantfile and to try again.

My second problem which I couldn't fix is: when I did ssh into my box, the **Code** directory was empty (My sites were gone!) and of course I couldn't access my sites. Instead, I get this error:

> No input file specified.

I should mention that I changed the **.ssh** folder too and made necessary changes to the **Homestead.yaml** file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: E:\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - E:\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ../laravel-cms
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: cms.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/cms/public
    - map: voting-app.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/voting-app/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

How can I fix these two problems?

Comment: I would suggest you uninstall and then reinstall to your required destination drive.

Comment: But when I was installing, it didn't ask where to install. "vagrant add box laravel/homestead"

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667030/download-vagrant-box-to-different-drive

Comment: And this https://github.com/saasbook/courseware/wiki/Setting-Up-Vagrant-Environment-on-Windows-Platform

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy your vagrant machine before moving it.

But let it where it is now and run `vagrant destroy --force`.
If this does not work open VirtualBox (GUI for your virtual machine) and remove the virtual machine from there. Then try a `vagrant up`.

Another way to destroy a vagrant machine:

```
vagrant global-status
```

There you'll get a list of all your vagrant machines. Those have an id, you have to copy this id and run `vagrant destroy <id> --force`.
Then again `vagrant up`, which will create a new virtual machine with the correct path.

Comment: not, you will not lose anything from your shared files, but when you are doing things like this you must have a backup.

Comment: But one question: when I execute the "vagrant provision", it suggests me executing the "vagrant init". Does it solve my problem?

Comment: do you have VagrantFile file ?

Comment: No. I don't have this file and this is exactly why this problem happened. I don't know what has's happened to this file (VagrantFile) during my moving process.

Comment: so that's your problem

Comment: try to get it back somehow, and follow the steps above

Comment: but it's not possible! I moved everything. Why is this file gone?

Comment: dont know, sorry

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. How does Homestead (the file I cloned from github) know that I changed the .vagrant.d to another location?

Comment: there is the Vagrantfile from laravel/homestad github account https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile