# Vagrant not respecting VAGRANT_HOME setting on Windows 8.1

Tags: vagrant, windows-8.1

I'm currently using PuPHPet to deploy a Vagrant box locally on Windows 8.1 64-bit, and I'm using the latest versions of Virtualbox and Vagrant both. I set the env variable VAGRANT_HOME in:

- Window's environment variables for both current user and system wide.
- setx VAGRANT_HOME "new dir" (In an admin cmd prompt, double checking with regedit)
- In the command prompt before calling vagrant up

And none of them are honored. I've tried defining it as O:.vagrant.d and O:\.vagrant.d both and it **still** uses the folder on my C drive, in my user directory.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try `set VAGRANT_HOME="/o/.vagrant.d/"` (temporary) or `setx VAGRANT_HOME "/o/.vagrant.d/"` (permanent) for `O:/.vagrant.d/` (Taken from ivica's answer to [vagrant.d outside of the home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733681/vagrant-d-outside-of-the-home-folder))